# using anchor tag I dont want to call the href

Tags: javascript

so for example I have

```
<a href="//www.altavista.com">AltaVista</a>
```

for the sake of this exercise I dont want to go to the altavista site. I want to call a function that loads an alert instead...so I have tried...

```
  <a onClick="registerHandlers(); return false;" href="//www.altavista.com">Yahoo!</a><br/>

<script>
function registerHandlers() {
alert("hi");
}
</script>
```

this is not working does anyone know why

Comment: Works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/cue47utt/

Comment: Are there any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: Are you getting the alert before it goes to the other site?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the link's dafault link behaviour. And if want to use jquery to add some event handles, `return false` is not recommended as it will also prevent all other event handlers on that element from running.

```js
function registerHandlers(e) {
  if (e.preventDefault) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  alert('hi');
}
```

```html
<a onClick="registerHandlers(event)" href="//www.altavista.com">Yahoo!</a><br/>
```